# Do all orbits have the same dimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory

Well, I've already asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025428/do-all-of-the-orbits-have-the-same-dimensions) at math.SE — but no-one's answered or commented. So now I'm posting it here (it's about the research paper — I think that it isn't an off-topic for this forum) — if it's breaking the rules, tell me about that, please.

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and let $X$ be a $G$-variety. It's stated in the paper [Dufresne and Kraft - Invariants and Separating Morphisms for Algebraic Group Actions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4299) (p.13) that all orbits are closed and have the same dimension if the graph
$$\Gamma_{X}\mathrel{:=}\{(g x, x) \mid g \in G, x \in X\}=\bigcup_{x \in X} G x \times G x \subset X \times X$$
is closed.

They say that the statement about the dimensions is true because "$G x \times\{x\}=p_{2}^{-1}(x)$ where $p_{2}: \Gamma_{X} \rightarrow X$ is the second projection."

But I don't understand this reasoning (the "dimension of the fiber" argument is legal only for "general fibers", isn't it?). Can someone explain it, please?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension, i.e. that if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of varieties then $\dim_x(f^{-1}(f(x)))$ is an upper semicontinuous function on $X$.

The assumption that $\Gamma_X$ is closed implies that it is a variety and that orbits are closed.

There are then two morphisms of varieties:
$$\pi_2:\Gamma_X \to X $$
and
$$G\times X \to X\times X$$
$$(g,y)\mapsto (g.y,y).$$

Take $x \in X$. The fiber of $x$ under the first morphism is its orbit, while the fiber of $(x,x)$ under the second morphism is isomorphic to the stabilizer. Hence the sum of the dimensions of these two fibers is $\dim(G)$. Both of these dimensions can only jump up at a limit point of a curve. Hence if $G$ and $X$ are connected they are constant.

---

It may be useful to be a bit more explicit.

1. It may seem as though we applied the semicontinuity theorem to limits in $X$ and not in the domain of each of the two morphisms under consideration. But both the morphism $\Gamma_X\to X$ and the composition $G\times X \to X\times X \overset{p_2}{\to} X$ here have right inverses $\phi:X\to \Gamma_X$ and $\psi:X \to G\times X$, given by $\phi(x)=(x,x)$ and $\psi(x)=(e,x)$. We are really applying semicontinuity to limits in the image of $X$ in $\Gamma_X$ and in $G\times X$ under these right inverses.
2. This argument works in case $X$ is irreducible. If it is not, since we assume $X$ is connected, we can apply it to each irreducible component separately. Whenever two irreducible components intersect it is then clear that their orbit dimensions are equal; connectivity yields the result.

(I get confused between left and right inverses, but I think I have it right this time.)

Comment: Gevayashfe : though it is obvious, it would perhaps be useful to add at the end of your answer that the sum of the dimension of the orbit and the dimension of the stabilizer is constant equal to the dimension of $G$? It would perhaps make your argument more transparent?

Comment: @Libli Thank you for the useful suggestion. I added this, and also explained the use of semicontinuity in more detail.